# Cannot run job with USE_CURRENT_SESSION = TRUE

Tags: oracle, plsql, scheduler, jobs

I have a terrible problem, which i'm struggling with.
We have 2 environments: one for developing, one for testing.

I just migrated some code to test environment and it does not work.

To not run into details i'm running a job, which creates zip.
Everything works ok on dev (after granting some privileges), but crashes on test.

The error is something like this:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-27370: job slave failed to launch a job of type EXECUTABLE
ORA-27300: OS system dependent operation:accessing extjob wrapper failed with status: 13
ORA-27301: OS failure message: Permission denied
ORA-27302: failure occurred at: sjsec 3
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 150
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 441
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get through this?
The worst thing is i must go with every idea with administrator.

The weird thing is that when i run job with USE_CURRENT_SESSION = false it works!

Credentials didn't help.

---

To answer all question here is the sample code that reproduces the error:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(  
    JOB_NAME => 'LS',  
    JOB_TYPE => 'EXECUTABLE',
    NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS => 1,
    JOB_ACTION => '/bin/ls',
    ENABLED => FALSE,
    AUTO_DROP => TRUE
  );

  DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE('LS', 1, '/tmp');
END;  

BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB('LS', FALSE); -- no error
END;

BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB('LS', TRUE); -- error
END;


SELECT * FROM USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS;
```

I tried even running with oracle user credentials. It did not help.
/tmp is also a directory object, but is there any connection?

db version: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Going to need to see the code.

Comment: or a very small test case that replicates the same problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

With USE_CURRENT_SESSION = false the job is running in background process with with permissions of an account owning background process.

USE_CURRENT_SESSION = true - your sessions, your account's permissions.

You are trying to create a file in DIRECTORY object?
Does you account has write permission for the folder that DIRECTORY object points to?